# Solving three nonlinear equations using matrices, or a different method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant, nonlinear-system

I have the following three equations:

$$r- q\delta_1 - q\delta_2 - q\delta_3 + p\delta_1\delta_2 + p\delta_1\delta_3 + p\delta_2\delta_3 - N\delta_1\delta_2\delta_3=0\tag{1}$$

$$s- r\delta_1 - r\delta_2 - r\delta_3 + q\delta_1\delta_2 + q\delta_1\delta_3 + q\delta_2\delta_3 - p\delta_1\delta_2\delta_3=0\tag{2}$$

$$t- s\delta_1 - s\delta_2 - s\delta_3 + r\delta_1\delta_2 + r\delta_1\delta_3 + r\delta_2\delta_3 - q\delta_1\delta_2\delta_3=0\tag{3}$$

- $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, $t$ are arbitrary real numbers. $N$ is an integer.
- $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$, and $\delta_3$ are the unknowns.

Is there a method using matrices (or otherwise) that allows derivation of algebraic expressions for $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$, and $\delta_3$ using $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, $t$, and $N$?

I know that there is a solution, and all* $\delta_n$ are real numbers.

*Maybe not all, but at least three.

---

My attempt for deriving an expression for $\delta_1$ from $(1)$, plugging it into $(2)$, deriving $\delta_2$ and plugging it into $(3)$ will most likely work, but very fast it becomes an arithmetic nightmare and I am certain there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first solve the linear equations in the variables
$$
x = \delta_1 + \delta_2 + \delta_3\\
y = \delta_1\delta_2 + \delta_1\delta_3 + \delta_2\delta_3\\
z = \delta_1 \delta_2  \delta_3
$$
so that $\delta_i$ will be the roots of the degree 3 polynomial
$$
\lambda^3 - x\lambda^2 + y\lambda-z=0.
$$

Comment: (i.e. the Vieta formulae)

Comment: But in your polynomial, $\lambda$ is the unknown and $x$, $y$, $z$ are known numbers, no? But they are made from my unknown $\delta$, so how do I solve the polynomial?

Comment: @Gimelist your 3 equations are a linear system in $x,y,z$, so you can solve it

Comment: @Exodd so just to make sure I understand the process. After changing to $x,y,z$ my system becomes a simpler linear system of equations, and then I can express each of them ($x,y,z$) in terms of $p,q,r,s,t,N$ which are just numbers. Then I plug those numbers into the cubic polynomial, and then my solutions for $\lambda$ are equal to my $\delta$?

Comment: exactly, the three solution of the cubic equation are your $\delta$s

Comment: One last question - is there any reason why writing the polynomial as $\delta^3 -x\delta^2+y\delta-z=0$ should be avoided? Looks slightly more convenient to me, one less symbol, and it makes it obvious that the roots are $\delta_i$.

Comment: you can use whatever variable you want, as long as it is clear for you

Comment: @Exodd is there a textbook or a paper that explains this topic in a bit more detail? There's a short discussion in Wikipedia, but I was wondering about the existence of a more authoritative source.

Comment: what topic in particular?

Comment: @Exodd Vieta's formula

Comment: @Gimelist Sadly, I'm not from an english-speaking country, so I don't know basic-level textbooks in english. Vieta's formula are usually high school or college first year level. try https://sites.math.washington.edu/~mathcircle/circle/2012-13/hw_2013_winter/VietasFormulas.pdf and https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/daltizio/Vietas%20Formulas.pdf